# Different resources for same language but different screen resolution

Tags: android, size, screen, resolution

Is it possible to use different texts for the same string and language in different screen resolutions?

Example:
Take the word Cancel, which in german is Abbrechen. Would it be possible to use *Abbrechen* in higher screen densities like **xxhdpi** and the reduced word *Abbrech.* for the rest?

I have tried to define two language files with the same name and the same string in the folders: **values-de** and **values-de-xxhdpi**, but this is not working because the language takes precedence and all mobiles uses the same definition, in this case the ones defined in **values-de-xxhdpi** overwrites the values in **values-de**.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dimens.xml` resources. For example, create a file `res/values-de/dimens.xml` for german and `res/values-fr/dimens.xml` for france.

In *dimens.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <resources>
    <dimen name="f_size">16sp</dimen> 
  </resources>
```

In your *Layout.xml*

```
<TextView
    android:textSize="@dimen/f_size"/>
```

May this helps

**EDIT:**

String dependents on screen-resolution:

```
float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
if (density >= 4.0) {
    tv1.setText(getString(R.string.xxxhdpiXY));
    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
}
if (density >= 3.0) {
    tv1.setText(getString(R.string.xxhdpiXY));
    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
}
if (density >= 2.0) {
    tv1.setText(getString(R.string.xhdpiXY));
    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);
}
if (density >= 1.5) {
    tv1.setText(getString(R.string.hdpiXY));
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
}
if (density >= 1.0) {
    tv1.setText(getString(R.string.mhdpiXY));
    tv1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is not with different languages, but with the same language in different resolutions. I would like to use two different values for the same string/language depending on the device screen resolution.

Comment: Oh okay. I think this is only possible by code. Create the same string for multi resolutions and set it with `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`